# Windows 7 File Date Question

Tags: windows, file, file-attributes, filetime, file-properties

apologies for not asking a strictly programming question, but this will move on to programming once my confusion is cleared.

i am about to write a program that can modify file date stamps like created, modified, last accessed date.

as i am investigating on Windows 7, it seems to provide more date fields. [example image here http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1281/datee.jpg](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1281/datee.jpg)

exactly how many file attributes are stored by the OS? i want to wipe all date fields, so i need to know which attributes are stored in the file and which are operating system generated.

thanks for reading. look forward to your insights.

**EDIT:** just found [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Change-the-properties-for-a-file) on the web, which makes my intended application not worth developing. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For different data types such as audio, video and image files, the OS will show additional data that it determines from the header of the file.

E.g., for images, it will use [EXIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) data that contains all kinds of info about shutter speed, aperture,etc. There may also be additional date info here.